# What's CBG's meaning in chatting

Tags: meaning-in-context, acronyms

I enter a chatting room and see many lines of 'CBG' in its chatting history,

I learn that it acronym of 'creeping bald guy' whereas still cannot get its point.

Comment: CGB, or CBG? The first of those would seem to be in the wrong order.

Comment: sorry, it's CBG @NathanTuggy

Comment: And likely "Creepy" rather than "Creeping"

Comment: If it's SO's python room...cbg ~ cabbage ~ sopython's 'salad language' for 'hello'.

Comment: [Salad language](https://sopython.com/salad/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's not "Chill Black Guy"?  In this context, "chill" is used as an adjective to mean "relaxed" and "cool".

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=CBG

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS95aL5pJjs).